# Output Noise Power for ODE

Tags: noise, differential-equation

My system is described by the following ODE:

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}y(t)}{\mathrm{d}t} = a-y(t)x(t)
$$

Where $a$ is a constant and x(t) is a poisson process so that:

$$
E[x(t)x(s)] = qI\delta(t-s)
$$

The solution is of the form:

$$
y\left( t \right) = e^{-\int^t{x(z)dz}}{\int^t{a\,e^{\int^z{x(w)dw}}}dz+ c}
$$

I would like to find a close form for the output total power $E[y^2(t)]$ in function of time.

Comment: Where is the $t$ in the final equation? After $\int x(t) dt$, the $t$ is integrated away so it is just a number at that point, call it $z$. Then according to your equation you'd have $y(t)=e^{-z}\int ae^zdt + c$, and this isn't too bad to solve. I feel like there is a typo or I am misreading something

Comment: Maybe it should be rewritten as $y(t) = e^{-\int^t{x(z)dz}}{\int^t{a\,e^{\int^z{x(w)dw}}}dz+ c}$